# How to avoid out of memory error in android

Tags: android

I am getting the value from webservice while unescape xml value. I am storing it in a stringBuffer. I am getting a lot of values from webservice. So I am getting out of memory error. Can anybody tell me how to avoid that?

My UnescapeXml code:

```
public  String unescapeXML(String str) {
            if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
              return "";

            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            int len = str.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
              char c = str.charAt(i);
              if (c == '&') {
                int pos = str.indexOf(";", i);
                if (pos == -1) { // Really evil
                  buf.append('&');
                } else if (str.charAt(i + 1) == '#') {
                  int val = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i + 2, pos), 16);
                  buf.append((char) val);
                  i = pos;
                } else {
                  String substr = str.substring(i, pos + 1);
                  if (substr.equals("&amp;"))
                    buf.append('&');
                  else if (substr.equals("&lt;"))
                    buf.append('<');
                  else if (substr.equals("&gt;"))
                    buf.append('>');
                  else if (substr.equals("&quot;"))
                    buf.append('"');
                  else if (substr.equals("&apos;"))
                    buf.append('\'');
                  else if (substr.equals("&nbsp;"))
                      buf.append(" ");

                  else
                    // ????
                    buf.append(substr);
                  i = pos;
                }
              } else {
                buf.append(c);
              }
            }
            return buf.toString();
          }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post your code? Also are you trying to store the xml as string then parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch to streaming the data and unescaping it as part of a custom Stream or Reader class as opposed to trying to read everything at once.

Comment: can you give example how to do with streaming the data

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are doing but it actually looks like you are simply replacing the html entities with the according character. There are already functions provided in the `Document` class. You might be looking for `normalizeDocument()`. You should really use streams instead of strings in this case.

[Document Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html)